Objects with distinct values are writen to a deque but when reading them all but the first have the same value (involving Poisson Sampling)
This code creates a client class with variables name, arrival time, and delay. The loop creates new clients in a queue by reading their arrival time, adding a delay to it, and make it the arrival for the new client. When appending the client objects to the queue all are distinct, however when I try to read them they become the same for only the arrival time. Why does this happen?
import random
import numpy as np
import collections

# a client class for creating a queue using a poisson distribution. The clients are added to a deque
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = random.choice(["Juan", "julia", "Daniel", "Rafael", "Lida", "Sandra"])
        self.arrival_time = 0
        self.arrival_time_delay = np.random.poisson(5, size=1)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Client: {} arrival-time: {} delay {}".format(self.name, self.arrival_time, self.arrival_time_delay)


client_count = 5
queue = collections.deque()

# arrival
time_added = 0
# adding clients to a deque 
for _ in range(client_count):
    client = Client()
    # a new time is the arrival time plus a delay for the next client to appear
    client.arrival_time = time_added
    print(client)
    queue.append(client)
    time_added += client.arrival_time_delay

print(60 * "#")

for c in queue:
    print(c)

#results:
#Client: julia arrival-time: 0 delay [6]
#Client: Sandra arrival-time: [6] delay [3]
#Client: Lida arrival-time: [9] delay [4]
#Client: Juan arrival-time: [13] delay [8]
#Client: Sandra arrival-time: [21] delay [6]
############################################################
#Client: julia arrival-time: 0 delay [6]
#Client: Sandra arrival-time: [27] delay [3]
#Client: Lida arrival-time: [27] delay [4]
#Client: Juan arrival-time: [27] delay [8]
#Client: Sandra arrival-time: [27] delay [6]


After the first Client has been put into the queue, time_added becomes a Numpy array, rather than a number.  (Notice all the square brackets in the output?)  You're storing that very same array in each subsequent Client's arrival_time field, you're merely changing the number it contains.  The simple fix would be to get rid of the size= parameter in the call to poisson(), so that it returns a number instead of an array.

That fixed the problem. However, I don't understand why in the creation phase it works fine

In the creation phase, you're printing the Clients one at a time, as they are created.  At that point in time, the values shown are correct - but in the process you've changed all of the previously-enqueued Clients, due to the shared array.
